# latex source code to epub

Tags: pdf, conversion, sourcecode, epub

I wrote a book that consists, basically, of images and tables, and the conversion pdf --> epub gives horrible results. The very appealing index in the pdf (with hyperlinks) looks gorgeous, but after conversion it looses all of its beauty. The contents of a table's cell  shifts column, and some other issues. Is there a way to generate epub file "directly" from latex source?

Comment: see tex4ebook..

Comment: I thank you your suggestion. In these days I tried to apply tex4ebook but, my book is made up mainly of tables and images and didnot obtain the result that xelatex gives. Cheers

Comment: if you gave an example, the tex4ht maintainers are here and could probably help make a suitable configuration. But as it is I don't think it is possible to give any answer, I suggest closing the question.